# Regex - match if at least 2 words out of N words, in any order

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regex expression that will create a match if a string has at least 2 words out of N. For example, take the words ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'). This regex should return a match for all these cases:

```
one two three four
twothreeone
two plus two is four
```

It should not return a match for:

```
one
three plus three is three
```

I have tried something like this`'/^(?=.*one)(?=.*two)(?=.*three)(?=.*four).+/'`, but this will only match if all words `('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')` are contained in the string.

Comment: You can do something like: `(one|two|three|four).*(?!\1)(?:one|two|three|four)` but it's more simple to test each word with a basic string function and to stop once you have two results.

Comment: That was one of the solutions I came up with, but I actually have many more words (about 30) that I need to check, so I was hoping for something that wouldn't require me to type everything twice.

Comment: In Perl/PCRE you can use a reference to a subpattern in a capture group with `(?n)` where n is the number of the capture group. So: `(one|two|three|four).*(?!\1)(?1)`. In the worst case, you don't have to type everything twice when you know the shortcuts ctrl+c and ctrl+v

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, it works!  Nice find, learn something new every day!  No copy-paste needed with PCRE, indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for stealing someone's comment, but it does appear to work!

> In Perl/PCRE you can use a reference to a subpattern in a capture group with (?n) where n is the number of the capture group. So: (one|two|three|four).*(?!\1)(?1). In the worst case, you don't have to type everything twice when you know the shortcuts ctrl+c and ctrl+v – Casimir et Hippolyte 4 hours ago

```
% pcretest 
PCRE version 8.35 2014-04-04

  re> #(one|two|three|four).*(?!\1)(?1)#
data> one one one
No match
data> one two one
 0: one two
 1: one
data> one four
 0: one four
 1: one
data> four four
No match
data> ^D
%
```

Indeed, in [pcre](http://ports.su/devel/pcre), which is a popular library used by [nginx](http://ports.su/www/nginx) (the only dependency of the whole nginx port in OpenBSD ports!) and lots of other software, you can use something like `(?1)` (or `(?-1)`) to refer to the previous pattern, so, you don't have to copy-paste the thing several times, as well as the negative look-ahead, which is just standard fare.

Here's the docs on the features at stake — you may want to look into the `pcrepattern` and `pcresyntax` manual pages, sections as below:

- http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC19

  http://mdoc.su/f/pcresyntax.3#LOOKAHEAD_AND_LOOKBEHIND_ASSERTIONS

  ```
   (?!...)     negative look ahead
  ```
- http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC21

  http://mdoc.su/f/pcresyntax.3#SUBROUTINE_REFERENCES_(POSSIBLY%09RECURSIVE)

  ```
   (?n)        call subpattern by absolute number
  ```
- http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC24

  http://mdoc.su/f/pcrepattern.3#SUBPATTERNS_AS_SUBROUTINES

etc.

In general, the http://www.pcre.org/original/pcre.txt and http://www.pcre.org/pcre2.txt pages include complete documentation, and are helpful in searching up that syntax you've seen somewhere.

Comment: *"Apologies for stealing someone's comment"*: not a problem, I was free to write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Search for two copies of a target word, but capture the first and apply a negative lookahead on the second word using a back reference to the first group to assert that a *different* word appeared in the second group - making (at least) 2 in total.

```
(one|two|three|four).*(?!\1)(one|two|three|four)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/xT5fmEtnEQ).

Answer (score 2):

```
(one|two|three|four).*(?!\1)(?-1)
```

Explanation:

- Capture one of the words in the group
- Find any amount of characters
- If you find what was matched in the last group don't match
- Unless you find another match of the group one behind this one (recursive subpattern)

This will mean when you edit it, you'll be able to just edit one capture group, assuming you're using PCRE regex (with say, PHP).

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lxrJ3B/1)

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense to use a relative reference to a sub-pattern `(?-1)` if you use at the same time an absolute back-reference `\1` for the same group. In short, write `(one|two|three|four).*(?!\1)(?1)` or `(one|two|three|four).*(?!\g{-1})(?-1)` but not `(one|two|three|four).*(?!\1)(?-1)` or `(one|two|three|four).*(?!\g{-1})(?1)`